# Python how to sort each line of the student's Final Mark in the file according from the highest to lowest

Tags: python, sorting

i am making a program where it read the file content and display the module code, student number, student name and the final mark from highest to lowest. so far i had sorted the final mark with a quick sort.

This is the content of my file, 77.5 is the final mark by the sum of 17.5, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0 and followed by the others

```
DICT 201707011 Johnny_Guy 77.5 17.5 20.0 20.0 20.0
DICT 201707012 Jenny_Girl 70.0 17.5 17.5 17.5 17.5
DICT 201707013 Joshua_Tan 79.5 17.5 22.0 20.0 20.0 
DICT 201707014 Jamine_Butters 67.5 17.5 10.0 20.0 20.0
DICT 201707015 Jone_Davy 97.5 17.5 30.0 30.0 20.0
```

this is my code

```
from pathlib import Path
home = str(Path.home())
stdData = []  # store module code, student number and name
markData = []  # store the final mark of each student

def qsort(myList):
    if not myList:
        return []
    else:
        pivot = myList[0]
        remainingList = myList[1:]
        lessOrEqual = [ y for y in remainingList if y <= pivot ]
        greater = [ y for y in remainingList if y > pivot ]
        return qsort(greater) + [pivot] + qsort(lessOrEqual)

def sortedMark():
    with open(home + "\\Desktop\\PADS Assignment\\test(sorted).txt", "a") as f:
        with open(home + "\\Desktop\\PADS Assignment\\test(unsorted).txt", "r") as f1:
            lines = [line.split() for line in f1]  # convert each line in file into 2d array
            print(lines)
            for a in lines:
                moduleCode = a[0]  # DICT is the module code
                stdNum = a[1]  # 201707011 and so on is the student number
                stdName = a[2]  # Jonny_Guy and so on is the student name
                finalMark = a[3]  # 77.5 and 70.0 and so on is the final mark
                markData.append(finalMark)  # append final mark of lines in each line into an array
                stdData.append(moduleCode)
                stdData.append(stdNum)
                stdData.append(stdName)
                finalSortMark = qsort(markData)
            print(finalSortMark)


sortedMark()
```

This is my output, the first output is the 2d array of the file and the second output is the sorted final mark of student with quicksort

```
[['DICT', '201707011', 'Johnny_Guy', '77.5', '17.5', '20.0', '20.0', '20.0'], ['DICT', '201707012', 'Jenny_Girl', '70.0', '17.5', '17.5', '17.5', '17.5'], ['DICT', '201707013', 'Joshua_Tan', '79.5', '17.5', '22.0', '20.0', '20.0'], ['DICT', '201707014', 'Jamine_Butters', '67.5', '17.5', '10.0', '20.0', '20.0'], ['DICT', '201707015', 'Jone_Davy', '97.5', '17.5', '30.0', '30.0', '20.0']]
['97.5', '79.5', '77.5', '70.0', '67.5']
```

Now the question is, how do i sort the module code, student number, student name, final mark from highest to lowest into a output file like this?

```
DICT 201707015 Jone_Davy 97.5 17.5 30.0 30.0 20.0
DICT 201707013 Joshua_Tan 79.5 17.5 22.0 20.0 20.0
DICT 201707011 Johnny_Guy 77.5 17.5 20.0 20.0 20.0
DICT 201707012 Jenny_Girl 70.0 17.5 17.5 17.5 17.5
DICT 201707014 Jamine_Butters 67.5 17.5 10.0 20.0 20.0
```

Comment: you do realize you're overriding an already reserved word `sorted`?

Comment: In your example, the final marks are sorted from lowest to highest, but you ask to sort it from highest to lowest. Which one do you mean?

Comment: ops , let me edit the question

Comment: Which fields do you want to sort on in order of precedence?

Comment: My suggestion: Read it to pandas first!

Comment: @wwii Sorry , my english is not that good, im assuming you want to know which order of the field to print out. the order is modulecode , studentNumber , student, finalMark , mark1, mark2, mark3, mark4.

Comment: Are you required to write your own sort function?

Comment: @Anton vBR what is pandas?

Comment: @wwii i am required to use a quicksort function to do the sorting or heapsort function. but i only know quicksort function.

Comment: @SomeGuy Pandas is basically Python's most common library to handle tables in multiple ways. As soon as you have a table read it to pandas and you will get help much faster.

Comment: @AntonvBR is this [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/) the one you talking about? if it is, i have no idea how to use it. I can try to youtube it get to know how to use it

Comment: If you are asking questions about a homework assignment, you state that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you making a list of the final marks (only)

```
markData.append(finalMark)  # append final mark of lines in each line into an array
```

Then sorting that list

```
finalSortMark = qsort(markData)
```

You should be sorting all the lines

```
[['DICT', '201707011', 'Johnny_Guy', '77.5', '17.5', '20.0', '20.0', '20.0'],
['DICT', '201707012', 'Jenny_Girl', '70.0', '17.5', '17.5', '17.5', '17.5'],
['DICT', '201707013', 'Joshua_Tan', '79.5', '17.5', '22.0', '20.0', '20.0'],
['DICT', '201707014', 'Jamine_Butters', '67.5', '17.5', '10.0', '20.0', '20.0'],
['DICT', '201707015', 'Jone_Davy', '97.5', '17.5', '30.0', '30.0', '20.0']]
```

*on* the 4th column (line[3])

You need to write `qsort` so that it excepts all the lines then sorts them on the 4th column.  To do that, for each line you need to extract the value of 4th column and use it determine if a line is greater than or less than another line.   When you recurse you need to pass the whole line(s) ...  in `qsort`, `greater` and `lessOrEqual` should each be a list of lists .

Comment: how do i do that? im a newbie to python

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to generalize your qsort function to take a second argument, a comparison function.  This function takes two arguments, and returns True if the first argument is less than or equal to the second one.

Here is such a function, which assumes that its two arguments are lists.  It compares element #3 in the list and ignores the others.  In your case, element #3 contains the final score. So that's what you want.

```
def compare_marks(mark1, mark2):
    return mark1[3] <= mark2[3]
```

Now your qsort function will look like this, replacing your explicit <= comparison with a call to the comparison function:

```
def qsort(myList, f_compare):
    if not myList:
        return []
    else:
        pivot = myList[0]
        remainingList = myList[1:]
        lessOrEqual = [ y for y in remainingList if f_compare(y, pivot)]
        greater = [ y for y in remainingList if not f_compare(y, pivot)]
        return qsort(greater) + [pivot] + qsort(lessOrEqual)
```

Finally, in the code that gathers the data into a big list to be sorted, you put each split line into the list instead of just one element of it:

```
def sortedMark():
    with open(home + "\\Desktop\\PADS Assignment\\test(sorted).txt", "a") as f:
        with open(home + "\\Desktop\\PADS Assignment\\test(unsorted).txt", "r") as f1:
            lines = [line.split() for line in f1]  # convert each line in file into 2d array
            print(lines)
            for a in lines:
                moduleCode = a[0]  # DICT is the module code
                stdNum = a[1]  # 201707011 and so on is the student number
                stdName = a[2]  # Jonny_Guy and so on is the student name
                finalMark = a[3]  # 77.5 and 70.0 and so on is the final mark
                markData.append(a)  # append split line to array
                stdData.append(moduleCode)
                stdData.append(stdNum)
                stdData.append(stdName)
                finalSortMark = qsort(markData)
            print(finalSortMark)
```

Now at the end of all this, each element in the list `finalSortMark` contains all the fields that were originally present in the files.  You can print it or write it to a file as you see fit.

I don't think you need the list `stdData` any more, but I left it in there so you could more easily spot the changes I made.

Comment: Instead of the two list comprehensions in `qsort`, why not just: `for thing in myList[1:]: if thing > pivot: greater.append(thing) ... else: lessOrEqual.append(thing)`

Comment: That would be better IMO but I was trying to modify the OP's original code as little as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I made something very simple.

```
x = """DICT 201707011 Johnny_Guy 77.5 17.5 20.0 20.0 20.0
DICT 201707012 Jenny_Girl 70.0 17.5 17.5 17.5 17.5
DICT 201707013 Joshua_Tan 79.5 17.5 22.0 20.0 20.0
DICT 201707014 Jamine_Butters 67.5 17.5 10.0 20.0 20.0
DICT 201707015 Jone_Davy 97.5 17.5 30.0 30.0 20.0"""

l = []
x = x.split("\n")
for n in x:
    n = n.split()
    l.append(n[3] + " " + " ".join(n))
    l.reverse()

l2 = []
for line in l:
    line = line.split()
    line.pop(0)
    l2.append(" ".join(line))

for line2 in l2:
    print(line2)
```

> ***OUTPUT***

```
DICT 201707015 Jone_Davy 97.5 17.5 30.0 30.0 20.0
DICT 201707013 Joshua_Tan 79.5 17.5 22.0 20.0 20.0
DICT 201707011 Johnny_Guy 77.5 17.5 20.0 20.0 20.0
DICT 201707012 Jenny_Girl 70.0 17.5 17.5 17.5 17.5
DICT 201707014 Jamine_Butters 67.5 17.5 10.0 20.0 20.0
```